# DbConnection picking wrong connection string

Tags: sql-server-ce, sqlclient, dbproviderfactories

Earlier i was using SQL Server Compact Data Provider to persist my data and connection string to point to my .sdf file where i intended to store the data. Later on i switched to the SqlClient Data Provider and a new connection string pointing to the SQL server and new database (.mdf).

The problem is when i am creating DbConnection object to open the connection it is picking the SQL Server Compact Data Provider's connection string even though i have removed all references of the  SQL Server Compact Data Provider and the connection string from my config file.

Is there any thing that i have missed ?

Update ------

I am using System.Data.SqlClient as dbprovider now and providing it with following connection string

```
<add name="ServerModel" connectionString="metadata=.\Server.csdl|.\Server.ssdl|.\Server.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='Data Source=servername\SQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=nServices;Integrated Security=True;Connection Timeout=60;multipleactiveresultsets=true'" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

and initalizing objectcontext object as following

```
ObjectContext= new objectContext(ServerModel);
```

which throws an exception syaing --
"Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0."

Where i am going wrong

Comment: Can you post you App.config, if you use one?

Comment: What data access technology are you using? ADO.NET just use connection strings?

Comment: I am using ystem.Data.SqlClient as dbprovider now and providing it with following connection string
<add name="ServerModel" connectionString="metadata=.\Server.csdl|.\Server.ssdl|.\Server.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='Data Source=servername\SQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=nServices;Integrated Security=True;Connection Timeout=60;multipleactiveresultsets=true'" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

and initalizing objectcontext object as